# Setting RDP initial program via local group policy

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop

I'm on Windowws 2008 server and I am trying to set the startup application for Remote Desktop sessions via the Local Group Policy Snap-in.

When I log in via RDP it does run my configured application, but it does not use the Working Directory I specified (It is always c:\windows\system32 no matter what I put in the box).  Are there any known issues with this functionality?

The same thing also happens when I configure an individual users 'Environment' settings to launch an app during login.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration]

Try to do this from Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this.  I'm pretty sure I used that setting and it still didn't work.  I'll try it again and let you know